# Spark: Scheduling Within an Application with scala/java

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

The [doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) states that it is possible to schedule multiple jobs from within one Spark Session / context. Can anyone give an example on how to do that? Can I launch the several jobs / Action, within future ? What Execution context should I use? I'm not entirely sure how spark manage that. How the driver or the cluster is aware of the many jobs being submitted from within the same driver. Is there anything that signal spark about it ? If someone has an example that would be great.

> **Motivation**: My data is key-Value based, and has the requirement that for each group associated with a key I need to process them in
>   batch. In particular, I need to use mapPartition. That's because In each
>   partition I need to instantiate an non-serializable object for
>   processing my records.

(1) The fact is, I could indeed, group things using scala collection directly within the partitions, and process each group as a batch.

(2) The other way around, that i am exploring would be to filter the data by keys before end, and launch action/jobs for each of the filtered result (filtered collection). That way no need to group in each partition, and I can just process the all partition as a batch directly. I am assuming that the fair scheduler would do a good job to schedule things evenly between the jobs. If the fair Scheduler works well, i think this solution is more efficient. However I need to test it, hence, i wonder if someone could provide help on how to achieve threading within a spark session, and warn if there is any down side to it.

More over if anyone has had to make that choice/evaluation between the two approach, what was the outcome.

**Note: This is a streaming application. each group of record associated with a key needs a specific configuration of an instantiated object, to be processed (imperatively as a batch). That object being non-serializable, it needs to be instantiated per partition**